# Exchange Web Services: prefer FindItem with PathToExtendedFieldType or PathToUnindexedFieldType restriction?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've inherited some code which uses Exchange Web Services to synchronize certain data between Exchange and an external system.

In order to solve some performance problems (including the generation of absurd amounts of transaction log files), I am in the process of rewriting large chunks of it, and I can see that when scanning for items on the Exchange server (with `FindItem`), I have the option of searching either for items with a certain value in an Extended Property (creating a search expression using `PathToExtendedFieldType`, or for items with a certain item class (which seems to be an unindexed field, so the search expression would have to use `PathToUnindexedFieldType`).

Is there a performance difference, or some general guidelines on which of the two to prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many times are you calling FindItem? If you are constantly calling it with different criteria then the server will create a lot of restrictions (search folders), which would result in the logging you see.

Comment: Hmm, that could explain it. We did call FindItem a lot (far too often). As I read the docs on [FindItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.finditemtype%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) though, it does not create search folders, since they say "If a specific search is performed regularly, it may be more appropriate to create a search folder for the search". Am I misinterpreting the docs?

Comment: It should be mentioned though, that we solved the problem by eliminating most of the FindItem calls. We're using pull subscriptions to keep track of updates now, which works a lot better.

Comment: Find item might be creating a hidden search folder, to satisfy the query. The problem is that a search folder is created for a specific criteria so the search folder for "size > 100KB" cannot be used to satisfy the query "size > 200KB".